# Não consigo importar um modulo de funcionalidade dentro do modulo principal. Angular

Tags: angular, angular-module

Tenho um modulo de funcionalidade chamado `CategoriasModule` e quando coloco o nome da classe nos imports do modulo principal aparece esse erro:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'.

Quando eu tiro o `CategoriasModule` do imports do `AppModule`, funciona tudo ok. Tem como eu usar o modulo sem importar no modulo principal? Se não, como eu resolvo esse problema?

app.module.ts:

```
...
import { CategoriasModule } from './categorias/categorias.module';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopoComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RodapeComponent,
    RestaurantesComponent,
    DiversaoComponent,
    OfertaComponent,
    ComoUsarComponent,
    OndeFicaComponent,
    DescricaoReduzida,
    OrdemCompraComponent,
    InfantilComponent,
    FitnessComponent,
    TeenComponent,
    CalcadosComponent,
    //CategoriasComponent
    BannerSlideComponent,
    OrdemCompraSucessoComponent,
    //ajustanto o erro ngIf

    //
  ],
  imports: [
    CategoriasModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    //ajustanto o erro ngIf

    ReactiveFormsModule,

    //
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [ 
    CarrinhoService, { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-Br' } 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  //
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
  //
})
export class AppModule { }
```

categorias.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoriasComponent } from './categorias.component';
import { Categoria01Component } from './categoria01/categoria01.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CategoriasComponent,
        Categoria01Component
    ],
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class CategoriasModule {}
```

Comment: Amigo, porque você quer colocar um module, dentro do module principal?

Answer (score 0):

Um Component só pode estar na sessão Declarations de 1 Modulo, e o componente  CategoriasComponent esta corretamente no modulo CategoriasModulo.

Agora pra você usar esse componente você tem suas formas ou colocar ele no AppModule dentro do Imports e Também do Exports(para exportar para outros componentes) ou então voce pode apenas importar esse modulo no imports do modulo do componente que voce vai usar, o que seria mais indicado, nesse caso nao precisa do exports, e o CategoriasComponent, voce nem precisa importar em nenhum modulo apenas no component onde voce vai usar, já que o CategoriasModulo já vai estar no import do modulo do componente em questão.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja acontecendo porque você não está exportando os componentes.

### Solução

**AppModule.ts**

```
...
import { CategoriasModule } from './categorias/categorias.module';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopoComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RodapeComponent,
    RestaurantesComponent,
    DiversaoComponent,
    OfertaComponent,
    ComoUsarComponent,
    OndeFicaComponent,
    DescricaoReduzida,
    OrdemCompraComponent,
    InfantilComponent,
    FitnessComponent,
    TeenComponent,
    CalcadosComponent,
    //CategoriasComponent
    BannerSlideComponent,
    OrdemCompraSucessoComponent,
    //ajustanto o erro ngIf

    //
  ],
  imports: [
    CategoriasModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    //ajustanto o erro ngIf

    ReactiveFormsModule,

    //
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [ 
    CarrinhoService, { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-Br' } 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  //
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
  //
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**categorias.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoriasComponent } from './categorias.component';
import { Categoria01Component } from './categoria01/categoria01.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CategoriasComponent,
        Categoria01Component
    ],
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    exports: [             // Modificado
        CategoriasComponent, 
        Categoria01Component
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class CategoriasModule {}
```

Teste Assim e Vê se Funciona. Espero ter Ajudado.